# How set caret position in tinyMCE?

Tags: vue.js, tinymce, vue-component, tinymce-4

I create TinyMCE based custom editor in Vue component.
After `@input` caret position sets to 0 (to left position)

so I get caret position

`window.tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getRng().startOffset`

but I can't set it

```
window.tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setRng(4)
window.tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<p>test test</p>')
```

not working also

```
var ed = window.tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection
ed.setCursorLocation(ed.getContent(), 3)
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE `selection.setRng()` doesn't take a number, it takes a [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) object.

Some good documentation on how this Range object works, can be found on [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/selection-range)

Here's an example on how to set your cursor to the beginning of the TinyMCE editor:

```js
//make it easier for yourself, we only get so many keystrokes in our lives
const editor = window.tinyMCE.activeEditor;
const selection = editor.selection;

//get the HTML element container
const container = editor.contentAreaContainer;

//get the first element of that container
const firstElementChild = container.firstElementChild;

//create a Range object
const range = new Range();

//set the start and end (start = end, as we want the selection to be collapsed; more info in the documentation above)
range.setStart(firstElementChild, 0);
range.setEnd(firstElementChild, 0);

//Set the editor's selection to our created range
selection.setRng(range, true); //true means it's selected forward; false for backwards selection
```

Answer (score 0):

In my editor I used this:

```
let rng = tinymce.DOM.createRng(); // the range object
var newNode = editor.dom.select('#_mce_temp_rob')[0];
rng.setStart(newNode.firstChild, 0); // 0 is the offset, it will be at the beginning of the line.
rng.setEnd(newNode.firstChild, 0);
editor.selection.setRng(rng);
```

Now I guess implementation will vary in your case as I did this while back and can't remember much of it but hope this helps you in some way.
More here: https://exceptionshub.com/whats-the-best-way-to-set-cursorcaret-position.html